# extracted data from one column to another i ms access

Tags: ms-access

I have a Address field with data(example:24 Gordon Street,Primrose,PRETORIA). Have a query with Like statement: Like "*PRETORIA*" as criteria in address field in the query to extract all address with PRETORIA in it. I want to know how to place PRETORIA or another city I choose to extract in a column/field called City in the same table or a new table with all the other fields also included in the table.

Answer (score 0):

To put the name of the city you have chosen in the same table, you can use an UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET City = "Pretoria" 
WHERE Address Like "*Pretoria"
```

However, this will not include addresses like Pretoria East. You could say:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET City = "Pretoria" 
WHERE Address Like "*Pretoria*"
```

The problem with this is that it will include Pretoria Avenue, which may not be in the city of Pretoria.

You show the name of the city in upper case, if this is always the case, you can say:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET City = "Pretoria" 
WHERE InStr(1,[City],"PRETORIA",0)>0
```

Which is a binary compare and will not match Pretoria.

To copy to a another table, you need to use a MAKE TABLE query (SELECT ... INTO) or an APPEND query (INSERT INTO).

```
SELECT * INTO MyNewTable
FROM MyTable
WHERE InStr(1,[City],"PRETORIA",0)>0
OR InStr(1,[City],"ALBERTON",0)>0

INSERT INTO MyNewTable 
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE InStr(1,[City],"BENONI",0)>0
```

It is not generally a goos idea to use * to indicate all fields (columns), but I  have done it here because I do not know your field names.

You may wish to read:

[`Fundamental Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140011%28office.10%29.aspx)
[`Intermediate Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140015%28office.10%29.aspx)
[`Advanced Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139977%28office.10%29.aspx)